# Calculus in an abstract space

Tags: calculus, sobolev-spaces

This is page 302 of PDE Evans, 2nd edition.

> **DEFINITIONS.** $\text{(i)}$ The Sobolev space $$W^{1,p}(0,T;X)$$ consists of all functions $\textbf{u} \in L^p(0,T;X)$ such that $\textbf{u}'$ exists in the weak sense and belongs to $L^p(0,T;X)$. Furthermore, $$\|\textbf{u}\|_{W^{1,p}(0,T;X)} := \begin{cases} \left(\int_0^T \|\textbf{u}\|^p + \|\textbf{u}'(t)\|^p \, dt \right)^{1/p} & (1 \le p < \infty) \\ \operatorname{ess}\sup\limits_{0 \le t \le T} (\|\textbf{u}(t) \| + \| \textbf{u}'(t) \|) & (p=\infty).\end{cases}$$
>
> **THEOREM 2** (Calculus in an abstract space)**.** Let $\textbf{u} \in W^{1,p}(0,T;X)$ for some $1 \le p \le \infty$. Then
>
> $\text{(i)}$ $\textbf{u} \in C([0,T];X)$ (after possibly being redefined on a set of measure zero).
>
> $\text{(ii)}$ $\textbf{u}(t)=\textbf{u}(s)+\int_s^t \textbf{u}' (\tau) \, d\tau$ for all $0 \le s \le t \le T$.
>
> $\text{(iii)}$ Furthermore, we have the estimate $$\max_{0 \le t \le T} \|\textbf{u}(t) \|\le C\| \textbf{u} \|_{W^{1,p}(0,T;X)}, \tag{7}$$ the constant $C$ depending only on $T$.
>
> **Proof.** 1. Extend $\textbf{u}$ to be $\textbf{0}$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and $T,\infty)$, and then set $\textbf{u}^\epsilon =\eta_\epsilon * \textbf{u}$, with $\eta_\epsilon$ denoting the usual mollifer on $\mathbb{R}^1$. We check as in the proof of Theorem 1 in §5.3.1 that $(\textbf{u}^\epsilon)' =\eta_\epsilon * \textbf{u}'$ on $(\epsilon, T-\epsilon)$.
>
> $\quad$Then as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, \begin{cases}\textbf{u}^\epsilon =\eta_\epsilon * \textbf{u} & \text{in }L^p(0,T;X) \\ (\textbf{u}^\epsilon)' =\eta_\epsilon * \textbf{u}' & \text{in }L_{\text{loc}}^p(0,T;X). \tag{8} \end{cases}
>   Fixing $0<s<t<T$, we compute $$\textbf{u}^\epsilon (t)=\textbf{u}^\epsilon (s) + \int_s^t \textbf{u}^{\epsilon '} (\tau) \, d\tau.$$ Thus $$\textbf{u}(t) = \textbf{u}(s)+\int_s^t \textbf{u}'(\tau) \, d\tau$$ for a.e. $0 < s < t < T$, according to $\text{(8)}$. As the mapping $t \mapsto \int_0^t \textbf{u}'(\tau) \, d\tau$ is continuous, assertions $\text{(i)}$, $\text{(ii)}$ follow.
>
> $\quad$2. Estimate $\text{(7)}$ follows easily from $\text{(9)}$.

I understand 1. in the proof, but not 2. How exactly may I use $\displaystyle \textbf{u}(t)=\textbf{u}(s)+\int_s^t \textbf{u}'(\tau) \, d\tau$, over the interval $[0,T]$ (with $s,t$ in between said interval) to prove that $$\max_{0 \le t \le T} \|\textbf{u}(t) \|\le C\| \textbf{u} \|_{W^{1,p}(0,T;X)}$$
Relation $\text{(7)}$ resembles the many previous estimates shown in Chapter 5 of Evans' textbook. I have finally finished reading the entirety of Chapter 5, but are there also any recommended sections I should review as general background for this? (If this is not applicable here actually, then please disregard this last paragraph.)

Comment: There is no (9) in the post ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you apply Hölder to get
$$
\|u(t)\| \leq \|u(s)\| + \int_0^T\|u'(\tau)\|\,\mathrm{d}\tau \leq \|u(s)\| + T^{1-1/p}\|u'\|_{L^p(0,T;X)} .
$$
Then, taking the $p$-th power of both sides, and integrating with respect to $s$, we have
$$
T\|u(t)\|^p \leq c\int_0^T\|u(s)\|^p\,\mathrm{d}s + cT\cdot T^{p-1}\|u'\|_{L^p(0,T;X)}^p
= c\|u\|_{L^p(0,T;X)}^p + cT^p\|u'\|_{L^p(0,T;X)}^p ,
$$
where $c=2^{p-1}$.

Comment: Okay, in applying Hölder's inequality in detail on the second term, I got $$\int_0^T |\textbf{u}'(\tau)| \, d\tau=\int_0^T |1||\textbf{u}'(\tau)| \, d\tau \le \|1 \|_{L^p} \| \textbf{u}'(\tau) \|_{L^p}$$ but how can I get $\|1 \|_{L^p}$ to be equal to the $T^{1-\frac 1p}$ you wrote above? (Sorry, it's been a while since my measure theory course which covered a bit of $L^p$ spaces.)

Comment: It is not the $L^p$-norm of $1$, but the $L^q$-norm, with $q$ satisfying $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$.

Comment: Now, what do you mean by integrating with respect to $s$? Specifically, how would one get to $$c\int_0^T|u|^p + cT\cdot T^{p-1}\|u'\|_{L^p}^p$$ which you wrote in your second line?

Comment: You see that there is a term $|u(s)|$ in the right hand side in the first line? We integrate with respect to that variable $s$. The left hand side and the second term in the right hand side are then just constants. By the way, I just noticed I am missing a $T$ in the left hand side, which should appear because of integration from $0$ to $T$.

Comment: So now I get $$|\textbf{u}(t)|^p \le C\left(\|\textbf{u}(s) \|_{L_p}^p + \|\textbf{u}(\tau)\|_{L_p}^p \right)$$ (I absorbed $T^p$ into the constant.) Do I now integrate both sides with respect to $t$, and manipulate somehow so that I arrive at $$\|\textbf{u}(t)\| \le C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}},$$ for all $t \in [0,T]$, which means $$\max_{0 \le t \le T} \|\textbf{u}(t)\| \le C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}}?$$

Comment: No you don't integrate over $t$, you just take the maximum over $t$ in the left hand side. You have the inequality for arbitrary $t$ which means you have the same for the maximum.

Comment: Note that all absolute value signs $|\cdot|$ I used must be replaced by the norm sign $\|\cdot\|_X$.

Comment: I thought about integrating over $t$ so that I could maybe express the left side as a norm, rather than an absolute value, but you said we shouldn't do that. However, I don't know how we can just "replace" the absolute value signs--in particular, the ones you have in your answer--with a norm.

Comment: What I mean is that I just used the absolute value sign for the norm, as it looks cleaner. Now I adjusted the notations so they are closer to your original notation.

Comment: Basically, the argument is the same if $u$ has values in a Banach space $X$, or if it is just a real valued function.